# Using save() method on Active Record is not updating, but it works fine if I use the update() method

Tags: yii2

I want to update some attributes of an [Active Record](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record) if it exists, or create a new one.

**My Active Record definition is**:

```
class CustomerRecord extends ActiveRecord
{
    public const ID = 'id';
    public const UID = 'uid';
    public const CUSTOMER_EMAIL = 'customerEmail';
    public const CUSTOMER_NAME = 'customerName';
    public const CUSTOMER_PHONE = 'customerPhone';
    public const CUSTOMER_MESSAGE = 'customerMessage';

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('customerEmail', 'required'),
        );
    }
}
```

**The controller is as follows**:

```
public function actionCreateCustomer(): Response
    {
        $this->requireSiteRequest();
        $acceptsJSON = Craft::$app->request->getAcceptsJson();
        $postData = array(
            CustomerRecord::CUSTOMER_NAME => Craft::$app->request->getRequiredParam('contactName'),
            CustomerRecord::CUSTOMER_EMAIL => Craft::$app->request->getRequiredParam('contactEmail'),
            CustomerRecord::CUSTOMER_PHONE => Craft::$app->request->getRequiredParam('contactPhone'),
            CustomerRecord::CUSTOMER_MESSAGE => Craft::$app->request->getParam('contactMessage'),
        );
        $response = MyModule::$instance->contactService->createCustomer($postData);
}
```

**The service is as follows**:

```
public function createCustomer(array $postData) {

        $isNewRecord = false;

        // Lookup for a customer with given id
        $customer = CustomerRecord::find()
            ->where([
                CustomerRecord::CUSTOMER_EMAIL => $postData[CustomerRecord::CUSTOMER_EMAIL]
            ])
            ->one();

        // Create customer if not found
        if (empty($customer)) {
            $customer = new CustomerRecord();
            $customer->setAttribute('customerEmail', $postData[CustomerRecord::CUSTOMER_EMAIL]);
             $isNewRecord = true;
        }


        $customer->setAttribute('customerName', $postData[CustomerRecord::CUSTOMER_NAME]);
        $customer->setAttribute('customerPhone', $postData[CustomerRecord::CUSTOMER_PHONE]);
        $customer->setAttribute('customerMessage', $postData[CustomerRecord::CUSTOMER_MESSAGE]);

        $customer->setIsNewRecord($isNewRecord);

        if($customer->validate()){
            $customer->save();
            return $customer->id;
        }else{
            return $customer->getErrors();
        }
    }
```

**Explanation about the service (where I think the problem is)**:

First thing, I try to find the existing record:

```
$customer = CustomerRecord::find()
->where([
CustomerRecord::CUSTOMER_EMAIL => $postData[CustomerRecord::CUSTOMER_EMAIL]
])->one();
```

This works fine, fine meaning: it returns the record I am looking for if it exists, and doesn't return it if it doesn't.

Then I update attributes as following:

```
$customer->setAttribute('customerName', $postData[CustomerRecord::CUSTOMER_NAME]);
$customer->setAttribute('customerPhone', $postData[CustomerRecord::CUSTOMER_PHONE]);
$customer->setAttribute('customerMessage', $postData[CustomerRecord::CUSTOMER_MESSAGE]);
```

This works fine too, because the data is inserted with said attributes.

```
if($customer->validate()){
   $customer->save();
   return $customer->id;
}else{
   return $customer->getErrors();
}
```

And as far as I know, `save()` will do an insert if `$customer->isNewRecord` is true, or update if `$customer->isNewRecord` is false. I printed those values and they are false and true as expected for each case.

When I use a new email, the record gets inserted correctly. But when I use an existing email, the correct customer id is returned but the update is not happening in the database.

**Interesting fact**:

If I do the following, it works perfect:

```
if($isNewRecord){
   $customer->insert();
}else{
   $customer->update();
}
```

As far as I know, the `save()` method does something similar. So i wonder why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Please add full action code of controller.

Comment: Add code related to user save and update logic, probably `->createCustomer($postData);` function logic loooks like it is used to save data to db.

Comment: @InsaneSkull Thanks again for your attention. But I added everything. The `contactService->createCustomer()` is described in the question with code attached.

Comment: I don't see new instance created or how you handle both cases. I believe you have some code like this `if ($customer) ...update else ..create new customer instance` then save logic. Might be your new customer logic overriding the update part.

Comment: @InsaneSkull Thanks again and sorry if I was unclear. I updated again with the full code. I didn't want to just paste full code to avoid making this seem like: "hey here we go, please solve this for me". Instead I pasted each piece that I considered relevant.

Comment: Don't worry about long code posting as long as you are stating the problem correctly and displaying your efforts. Many people make question like TLDR but you didn't so it's fine. You got suggestions right after adding appropriate code.  Don't be afraid to ask questions and help others when you can. Back to your question, change `if($customer->validate()){   $customer->save();   return $customer->id; }` to `if($customer->save())` it also validates the data before saving to db internally. So you can get validation error while saving in else part.

Comment: @InsaneSkull Thanks again. It sitll won't work. Fun fact. Doing ->update() instead of ->save() does update the record...

Comment: Still you were doing something wrong there, that breaks update try checking error logs when update fails there should be some mistake. `save()` do update and insert by itself. You don't even need `isNewRecord` flag, AR can identify it by looking at model instance.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the else clause after `if (empty($customer))`

```
        // Create customer if not found
        if (empty($customer)) {
            $customer = new CustomerRecord();
            $customer->setAttribute('customerEmail', $postData[CustomerRecord::CUSTOMER_EMAIL]);
        }else{
--->            $isNewRecord = true;
        }
```

So you are setting `isNewRecord` to true where it should be false.

Answer (score 1):

Just leave out the `else`-Part:

```
// Create customer if not found
if (empty($customer)) {
    $customer = new CustomerRecord();
    $customer->setAttribute('customerEmail', $postData[CustomerRecord::CUSTOMER_EMAIL]);
}
```

and it works.

Why? If there is a `$customer` found and you are setting `$isNewRecord = true;` Yii2 will make an `INSERT` SQL statement instead of a `UPDATE` statement and create a new record in the database. [See here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#save()-detail).

Comment: Further optimization: `$customer->customerEmail = ...`

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Really silly mistake on my side. I now updated this part and the INSERT is not taking place for already existing customers. But what I realized that there isn't any UPDATE being executed either. In what case would the `save()` method return success but NOT execute an update?. If I dump the value of $customer right before save(), it contains the updated values, but the update isn't happening in the DB.

Comment: Maybe validation fails. And check, if your `rules()` in the model are correct.

Comment: And: `save() ` already performs validation. So you can go with `if($customer->save())`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried removing the rules and also using save(false). In both cases the record is still not being updated. Is there any way I can dump the query that is being executed, so I can read the SQL query and detect any issues there? I'm sorry I am extending this, really appreciate your help.

Comment: Maybe your database rejects the update. If you add `'categories' => ['yii\db\*'],` in the config-log-target, you see the database statements in the `application.log`. Then try them manually using PhPMyAdmin or any other database frontend.

Comment: Thanks, I found out that the INSERT SQL statement happens. But the UPDATE SQL does not happen at all (it does not get logged). But the correct $customer->id is returned. What may be causing the SQL statement to not run? Validation is happening correctly because ->validate() returns true.